# Taking care of missing data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame about the rent price in São Paulo, but some values of "Latitude" and "Longitude" are missing, so I wanna replace the "0" with the mean. The thing is that I wanna replace the Latitude and the Longitude with the mean just of the same District.

A slice of the dataFrame bellow.

|  | Price | Condo | Size | Rooms | Toilets | Suites | Parking | Elevator | Furnished | Swimming Pool | New | District | Negotiation Type | Property Type | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 930 | 220 | 47 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | Artur Alvim/São Paulo | rent | apartment | -23.543138 | -46.479486 |
| 1 | 1000 | 148 | 45 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | Artur Alvim/São Paulo | rent | apartment | -23.550239 | -46.480718 |
| 2 | 1000 | 100 | 48 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | Artur Alvim/São Paulo | rent | apartment | -23.542818 | -46.485665 |
| 3 | 1000 | 200 | 48 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | Artur Alvim/São Paulo | rent | apartment | -23.547171 | -46.483014 |
| 4 | 1300 | 410 | 55 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | Artur Alvim/São Paulo | rent | apartment | -23.525025 | -46.482436 |

How can I do it?

Comment: Is there a extra column for the district or how do you get that knowledge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Pandas built in functions [.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [.agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html), [.assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), [.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), [.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```
means_mapping = (
    df
    .groupby("District")
    .agg(LongitudeMean=("Longitude", "mean"), LatitudeMean=("Latitude", "mean"))
    .reset_index()
).set_index("District").transpose().to_dict("list")

df = df.assign(
    Longitude=df["Longitude"].fillna(df["District"].map(means_mapping).apply(lambda x: x[0])),
    Latitude=df["Latitude"].fillna(df["District"].map(means_mapping).apply(lambda x: x[1))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple answer, below is the pseudo-code.

```
for i in range(len(pd.row)):
     if pd[i][Latitude] == 0 and pd[i][Longitude] == 0:
        //Do replace.
```

I am sorry that I forget the syntax of the pandas, but I think you can get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

first get the mean latitude and longitude for each district

```
df_meanll = df.groupby('District').agg(long_mean=('Longitude','mean'), lat_mean=('Latitude','mean')).reset_index()
```

replace the missing values from here, for example:

```
df = df.merge(df_meanll, on='District', how='left')
```

fill missing values as follows:

```
df.Longitude.fillna(df.long_mean, inplace=True)
df.Latitude.fillna(df.lat_mean, inplace=True)
```